# How can you set a site-level master page on the Web?

Tags: 2010, master-page, custom-masterpage

I have a SharePoint 2010 site collection that doesn't have publishing features enabled (on purpose), and was wondering if it was possible to set the site's default master page... without using SharePoint Designer.

[Microsoft's information about Master Page deployment](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-sharepoint-master-pages-HA102019628.aspx) is somewhat lacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append /_layouts/changesitemasterpage.aspx to your site URL. You will get the option you are looking for.

Comment: Whoa, you're right! Why isn't that option available in the Site Settings manager?